# Remove Line If It Contains Exact String From Line Of Another File

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a large file and would like to remove any lines from the file that contain an exact string listed in another file. However, the string must match exactly (I'm sorry I don't know how to describe this better).

Here is the file:

```
one@email.com,name,surname,city,state
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
three@email.com,name,surname,city,state
anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state
```

And here is the example list to filter with:

```
one@email.com
three@email.com
```

The desired output is:

```
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state
```

I have tried to do this using the following:

```
grep -v -f 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt
```

However this produces the output:

```
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
```

I assume it's doing this because "anotherone@email.com" contains "one@email.com". I've searched for a way to include beginning of the line, but not found anything suitable.

I'm open to doing in something other than grep too, I used grep because I couldn't figure it out any other way.

Comment: three@email.com != three@gmail.com

Comment: If you use GNU grep add option `-w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only like to print lines from first file that `does not` contains data from second file in the first field, then this should do:

```
$cat file
one@email.com,name,surname,city,state
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
three@email.com,name,surname,city,state
anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state
$cat filter
one@email.com
three@email.com

awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++;next} !($1 in a)' filter file
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state
```

For every line in the `filter` this creates an array `a` with the name and value to `1`
Like `a[one@email.com]=1` and `a[three@email.com]=1`
Then `awk` test line by line in the `file` against the array, giving

```
a[one@email.com]=1
a[two@email.com]=
a[three@email.com]=1
a[anotherone@email.com]=
```

Then print all line from the `file` without `1`

```
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and with the two massive files I was using. Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your input file contains `three@gmail.com` not `three@email.com` (typo perhaps)

```
$ grep -vw -f 2.txt 1.txt
two@email.com,name,surname,city,state
anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state
```

---

> **-w, --word-regexp** - 
>                The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by `[[:<:]]' and`[[:>:]]';

Comment: This may be some dangerous, since it not only search for the filter in first field of the file, but everywhere on the line.  So if the word is found at the end, its also remove the complete line.  Ex. it will remove this line `anotherone@email.com,name,surname,city,state,three@email.com`

Comment: @Jotne, the OP did not state the rule to search *"in **first** field of the file"*

Comment: True, that is why OP should read my comment and see that this solution does remove the line if the filter data are found anywhere in the line and he only looks for the first field.  Your solution may be ok for the OP.

Comment: @Jotne ok, let's wait for the OP's reaction

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - the email is only found in the first field, so it does work as expected. However, due to the size of the inputs this produced a memory error pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case -- process first file by building an associative array with filter lines being the index.  In subsequent files, test if the given line is not in the array indexes -- the default action of a pattern is to print.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    BEGIN   { split("", m) }
    NR==FNR { m[$0] = ""; next }
    !($1 in m)
' filter.txt file.txt
```

But... if we are looking to filter any occurrence of the string anywhere in the line (an unconstrained exact match) we need to do something less clever and more brute-force:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("", m)
        n=0
    }
    NR==FNR {
        m[n++] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            if (index($0, m[i]))
                next
        }
        print
    }
' filter.txt file.txt
```

Note that if the filter contains non-printable characters (e.g. non-unix line endings), we would need to deal with them by filtering them out (e.g. with `sub(/\r/, "")`).